# how i get map for particular area?

Tags: iphone

I don't know about map-view.I want map for particular area for that what to do?if it is possible then give me the answer with example and code.

Comment: are you asking about the google map API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about Google Map in iPhone SDK 3.0 then you need to look at **MKCoordinateRegion** and **MKCoordinateSpan** in MapKit framework.

You can set the co-ordinates of your map view by setting MKCoordinateRegion and zoom level by using **latitudeDelta** and **longitudeDelta** property of MKCoordinateSpan.

for example,

```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

   location.latitude=yourlatitude;
   location.longitude=yourlongitude;

   span.latitudeDelta=0.01;  //or whatever zoom level
   span.longitudeDelta=0.01;

   region.span=span;
   region.center=location;

   [mapview setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
   [mapview regionThatFits:region];
```

Hope that helps...